# Is puja only for going close to God and finally attaining moksha or it can be there for solving real world problem?

Tags: karma, rituals, worship, puja

I am quite confused because I am seeing different people say different things.

1. Some say Puja isn't for any materialistic gain or solving any life problem. Infact, thistype of puja and bhakts aren't true bhakts at all. Puja and worshipping at best gives us strength to face these life problems and nothing else. Additionally, our problems are a result of our own karma so deities aren't going to make us free of our own karma anyway.
2. Others say Puja can be done to solve life problems. Infact, Lord Ganesha is called Vignaharta and Lord Hanuman is called sankat mochak. There are even specific Pujas for specific problems like marriage. My mother sees a Pandit on Youtube who present Shiva mahapuran katha and there many devotees come and claim how their some problem(e.g. unemployment, disease etc.) got solved after they started worshipping Lord Shiva. This also goes gainst karmic doctrine because our problems are result of our own karma only.

Comment: Puja can be done to decrease fruits of some actions but we will have to face them anyway

Comment: Both are correct. The 1st case is that of nishkama bhakti & the 2nd is that of sakama bhakti. Nishkama bhakti is very difficult to obtain.

Comment: @অনু but if God gives us something or solves any problem won't it be against Karma doctrine?

Comment: A Puja that does not solve real life problems is not a Puja.

Comment: The basic karma doctrine stands - do good things, enjoy good results. Do bad things, suffer bad results. Now Vedanta philosophy states about the existence of God who is the karmaphaladata & states that by seeking God's grace, one can escape the cycle of karma. However Buddhists & Jains deny the existence of God & are in favour of minimizing interaction with the world in order to gradually reduce karmaphala.

Comment: Read chapter 17 of the Gita.

Answer (score 2):

> **ārto jijñāsur arthārthī jñānī cha bharatarṣhabha**
> distressed, the seekers of knowledge, the seekers of worldly possessions, and those who are situated in knowledge.
> (Gita 7.16,Swami Mukundananda)

speaks of 4 classes of devotees ( comprising of sakama/nishkama bhaktas) , who are in the different rungs of the same ascent.. Nishkama jnani bhakta who  is in constant union /have completely yielded to divine alone , is truly superior than a Sakama bhakta who  have nt crossed the world of duality , Although a Sakama pray for material benefits,   their act of seeking divine itself is regarded noble . bcos this attitude of seeking would help them progress in the ascent.So they too are lauded in Gita, **udārāḥ sarva evaite** (
All those who are devoted to Me are indeed noble) irrespective of sakama / nishkama says Gitacharya.

A Jiva is entitled to do karma  only in manushya loka , Karma is not possible elsewhere (as a pashu , pakshi or Deva etc)  **karmānubandhīni manuṣhya-loke**(BG 15.2).. So In order to perform any yajna , homa or Puja etc , even celestial may ve come to manushya loka .(as per several instances in various puranas)

A puja is definitely a virtuous act( done in shaastric way,though a Sakama devotion ),which is always preceded by a sankalpa comprising it's purpose . Sankalpa procedure standardizes  *Parameshwara preethyartham* and the result of the puja is bhakta anugraha by Parameshwara.It enables one become a vessel for divine grace apart from fulfilment of material wishes.(Etymology of पू is to make pure, cleanse, purify,and that of  Ja is  sprung from , born . So performing Puja enriches purity of mind .)

Sheer recital of Shiva Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram,Rama nama, Gayathri mantra / certain rites,  can mitigate the effect of sins (expiation),..This however does not mean the karma doctrine is refuted , as it is believed that any janma had occured only bcos of karma .. Puja is again a karma whose Karma Phala is positive with divine grace, so it should not be overlooked as some thing inferior as long as one hasn't crossed the duality.